# How to install applications on a windows docker container?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, containers, conan

I'm trying to create a **Docker container** based on the *abrarov/msvc-2019* (**windows based**) image and I need to install additional programs such as **Conan**.

In the **Dockerfile**, what do I need to write in it to be able to install **Conan**? I can't just use something like "apt install" since Windows doesn't support anything of the sort.  I can't find anything online about this.

I tried downloading the .exe installer locally and copy it inside the container, and then run the .exe during the building of the image. Something like this :

```
COPY conan-win-32_1_33_0.exe C:\\
RUN conan-win-32_1_33_0.exe;
```

But the image doesn't finish building and it's just stuck in the RUN part.

Comment: See [Install Conan](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html) maybe your image must have python ?

Comment: You're right, I can just install it with python since it's already installed in my image, that answers my questions. Although, I still don't know how to install other programs that don't have this convenience of being able to be installed through the command line (in this case, with pip).

Comment: I do recommend Chocolatey. It's a package manager for Windows, you can install most popular Windows apps using it (command line only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [most recommended way](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html) is using pip:

```
pip install conan
```

Another official ways are listed on [download](https://conan.io/downloads.html) page. But as you listed, Windows installer is the another way.

For Windows you still can try [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/conan), but it's not maintained by Conan team.

In the past we tried something similar and worked, a [MSVC 15 Docker image with Conan](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-docker-tools/blob/master/msvc_15/Dockerfile). However, due Visual Studio license, we can't build images for distribution. You could fork the project and use it for your own propose.